# Retrieving Card Verification Number In Magento produces empty result

Tags: php, magento

I am have inherited a Magento server for one of our e-commerce ventures and we have some fraud that was happening. There is a custom API that we use for CC processing and DB management and so forth, which we have to assign all the ordering and payment variables to feed into this API from Magento values.

We want to add the Card Verification field because we haven't required it to this point. Anyway, I activated the `Request Card Security Code` field in the `Payment Methods` section of the Magento Configuration and it does show up on the check-out screen now...however, when the submit is clicked and I try to retrieve the value by using `$payment->getCcCid()` on the `success.phtml` the security code is blank. When I do a debug (as suggested on other SO posts `$_order->getPayment()->debug()`) it doesn't show anywhere. I have `print_r($payment)` to see if the value is contained in their somewhere, but alas it is not.

**DEBUG ON SUBMISSION**

`$_order->getPayment()->debug()` produces:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 4619
    [parent_id] => 4619
    [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
    [shipping_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_amount_ordered] => 74.9500
    [amount_ordered] => 74.9500
    [cc_exp_month] => 3
    [method] => ccsave
    [cc_last4] => 1111
    [cc_owner] => Andrew 
    [cc_type] => VI
    [cc_exp_year] => 2016
    [cc_number_enc] => xSIyni0Ndvnaa4RZxLZS/w==
    [additional_information] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

**../template/checkout/success.phtml**

I can retrieve all these other fields, no problem, the security code is eluding me. I asked the folks who worked on this originally and their response was "That should work" when referring to what I did to retrieve:

```
// Value is assigned properly
$CC_NAME_1  =   $payment->getCcOwner();
// Value is assigned properly
$CC_NUM_1   =   preg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $payment->getCcNumber());
// Value is blank
$CSVCODE_1  =   $payment->getCcCid();
```

On a side note, there are no errors when assigning the `$payment->getCcCid()` so it's coming through blank. Any help from professional Magento developers who might know what I am missing would be great.

Comment: The CID may be collected and submitted to the gateway for authorization/capture but not stored per PCI-DSS. Looks like this was set up to follow that directive. Having it show on success.phtml would be a big no-no.

Comment: I don't want to display it, the success page is just where they applied the custom api so that's where I have to try and pull this number from. I have to grab the value from magento and send it to our custom API. Nothing gets displayed except a normal success or failure provided by Magento. The standard operation of Magento is unchanged.

Comment: Magento used to store the CVC (using blowfish ecb encyption) but no longer does in line with PCI compliance. The model variable still exists though. You will have access to the newly posted variable on your payment controller as it simply posted to the server so get it with $_POST and use die($_POST) in the controller, handle it there with regards to the gateway and be done with it without saving it to DB. Magento is not storing it in DB so you will not be able to echo it out on the success page like you are trying to do. Do not store it ever please.

Comment: This sounds promising! I appreciate the info. I will look into retrieving the `$_POST`, which I originally was trying to do, but I didn't know where to start because the success page has already been stripped of `$_POST` by the time all the API gets applied. Anyway, thanks for the info, I will check magento forums/help to try and figure it out, but this sounds like good info! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I need to do this it looks like, HOWEVER, when I do either of these, they are blank: `$this->getRequest()->getPost();` or `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();`....? Is it because it's cleared out by the time it hits this page or am I not retrieving it properly?

Comment: Yes, it is blank because the CID will have been used by a payment gateway after the submit button has been pressed and the transaction references received and logged. Since this information is no longer needed, it is discarded immediately and then the success page displayed. Most tricks with the success page are reading from the database at this point and since the CID was not stored, it will not be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, I had to retrieve and forward the CID from:

`/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

**For anyone interested, this was the flow:**

I created a custom class that added a `salt` and prepended it to the CID, encoded this new value, saved it to a `session` variable, then on the `success.php` page, I decoded, split out the `salt`, assigned the CID to a variable from the `session`, destroyed the session variable, then forwarded the new CID variable to the custom `API` for third party processing.

Thanks to those who commented, information supplied helped figure it out.

---

**EDIT - 2016/10:**

Since posting this, I have recreated this project and have *hopefully* implemented it a little better. I used an Observer on an event at the time of payment submission using the `sales_order_place_before` event allowing me to apply all the API at this point and use the success page as a success page.